# How can I set Qt to dynamically change window size based on gridLayout size?

Tags: qt

My program adds buttons to a gridLayout depending out the dimensions you give it. For example, if you gave it 10X10, it would open a new window with a 10X10 grid of QToolButtons. What I want to do is after it's done making the new window is to resize the window to the minimum that the grid layout is taking up. To do this, I have this statement set up:

```
this->resize((20 * number_of_rows) + (10 * (number_of_rows-1), (20 * number_of_columns) + ((number_of_columns-1) * 10 ));
```

The button dimensions are 20X20 and the spacing between them is 10. In theory, the code should make the window just big enough for the grid, but it doesn't. Here's what I get for an input of 15X1: the last button is cut off.
What I get for 30X1: only 24 buttons are shown, it's not wide enough.

Why is the size of the window not consistent?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out:`this->resize(ui->gridLayout->sizeHint());`
did the trick.